# Replace some text in an objects property?

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to request some information that comes in the form of an object. I need to replace some test in one of the properties and then write the list of objects to CSV.

When I do

```
Get-Process | select * | %{ $_Path.Replace("chrome", "ie") }
```

I have two problems

1. If $_.Path is null, it gives me an error that you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression
2. The output is a single string representing the text that was replaced (just the Path property). I need the original object and all of it's properties kept, but with the updated path value.

So of course when I try to do

```
Get-Process | select * | %{ $_Path.Replace("chrome", "ie") } | Export-Csv -Path "out.csv"
```

What I get is a single property Length because the output of the above is a string with only the Length property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Process | select * | %{ $_.Path = $_.Path.Replace("chrome", "ie"); $_ } | Export-Csv -Path "out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

- `$_.Path` instead of `$_Path`
- Assign the replaced text back to the path property
- and output the object after doing the assignment

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- [`Get-Process`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113324) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- `select` is an alias for [`Select-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- `%` is an alias for [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- [`Export-Csv`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113299) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 Get-Process | select *, @{N="Path";E={$_.Path.Replace("chrome", "ie") }} -ExcludeProperty Path | export-csv -Path "c:\temp\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```