# Is this the best way to replace text in all of an object's properties in powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace, newline

I have a large CSV file in which some fields have a new line embedded. Excel 2016 produces errors when importing a CSV with rows which have fields with a new line embedded.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315204/replace-some-text-in-an-objects-property), I wrote code to replace any new line in any field with a space. Below is a code block that duplicates the functionality and issue. Option 1 works. Option 2, which is commented out, casts my object to a string. I was hoping Option 2 might run faster.

Question: Is there a better way to do this to optimize for performance processing very large files?

```
$array = @([PSCustomObject]@{"ID"="1"; "Name"="Joe`nSmith"},
           [PSCustomObject]@{"ID"="2"; "Name"="Jasmine Baker"})

$array = $array | ForEach-Object {
    #Option 1: produces an Object, but is code optimized?
    foreach ($n in $_.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
        $_.PSObject.Properties[$n].Value = ` 
             $_.PSObject.Properties[$n].Value -replace "`n"," "
    }

    #Option 2: produces a string, not an object
    #$_ = $_ -replace "`n"," " 

    $_
 }
```

Keep in mind that in my real-world use case, each row has > 15 fields and any combination of them may have one or more new lines embedded.

Comment: I read somewhere that ForEach is faster than ForEach-Object.
You could do some testing of both scenarios you mention with the stopwatch class. Utilize it like so:
$resultstime = new-timespan -Minutes 1
$resultstime = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
$resultstime.Elapsed

Remember to stop it :)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll use the stopwatch class and time my original code compared with the suggestions from @wOxxOm.

Comment: Please do share your findings :)

Comment: Using my data set which is about 16.5 MB and 25,000 rows, the ForEach-Object loop ran in 36 seconds. The foreach loop ran in 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the fast [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) to read, process, and build the CSV from the file (PowerShell 3+):

  ```
  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') >$null
  $parser = New-Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser 'r:\1.csv'
  $parser.SetDelimiters(',')
  $header = $parser.ReadFields()

  $CSV = while (!$parser.EndOfData) {
      $i = 0
      $row = [ordered]@{}
      foreach ($field in $parser.ReadFields()) {
          $row[$header[$i++]] = $field.replace("`n", ' ')
      }
      [PSCustomObject]$row
  }
  ```
- Or modify each field *in-place* in an already existing CSV array:

  ```
  foreach ($row in $CSV) {
      foreach ($field in $row.PSObject.Properties) {
          $field.value = $field.value.replace("`n", ' ')
      }
  }
  ```

Notes:

1. `foreach` *statement* is much faster than piping to `ForEach-Object` (also aliased as `foreach`)
2. `$stringVariable.replace()` is faster then `-replace` operator

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'll try both of these approaches and see which is faster.

Comment: foreach is definitely faster than Foreach-Object. the replace loop takes 36 seconds with ForEach-Object and only 11 seconds with a foreach loop.

Comment: I also give up on trying to use -replace on an object. It seems to only turn the result into a string. 11 seconds is plenty fast for a twice weekly script.

Comment: Just to link questions, I've written a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67029635/7571258) for a different question, where I wrapped `TextFieldParser` in a reusable function.